# Can't boot after GRUB Configuration saved new configuration!

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.04, hardware, bootloader

I've just removed `acpi=off` in updated `Ubuntu 17.04` by Grub Customizer utility. And now I can't boot even with `acpi=off` parameter! I can see only white/orange dots on small rectangles in the center of the screen.

Also, I tried different kernels - 4.10.0.19, 33 (default) and 35 - with no success.

What can I do to fix it?

P.S. I'm using `MSI X299 SLI` motherboard. It has extremely buggy chipset `X299` on board. But it worked perfectly fine with updated Ubuntu until I saved the new GRUB configuration.

Comment: if you only want to put it back the way it was; the easiest (assuming you're comfortable with tty/terminal) is to press <E> (edit) instead of <enter> at the grub screen.  then add a " 1" (or " single") to the end of the "linux" line (so its forced to single-user or recovery-mode). it'll boot to text-terminal asking for password (always root for me; if you've not enabled root login it may be your username; I've never tried), where you cd;vim (or edit the file back to where it works; you're happy) then 'reboot'

Comment: But I can edit to where it was just by adding `acpi=off`after pressing <E>. And it doesn't help! It's really wired.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add `acpi=off` boot parameter.
2. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` after unsuccessful boot.
3. Run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` commands.

Now I can boot but can't login. Also I can't use `Ctrl+Alt+F1` anymore. Ubuntu is so buggy! Unbelievable.

4. Select kernel 33 instead of 35 and it works again.

But what happened? It looks like I just restarted Ubuntu during update in background. And it just stopped to boot because I restarted it after launching `Grub Customizer`! It's not an operational system. It's garbage.